# Kythe code indexing processes being throttled despite normal CPU temperature

Tags: parallelism, cpu-usage, temperature

I'm running into an issue with CPU throttling that only seems to trigger under a specific workload of running the [Kythe indexer](https://kythe.io/examples/#indexing-compilations). Detailed repro steps at the end of the question. I'm going to give a high level summary here.

Kythe is a tool for extracting indexes from source code. I'm running Kythe under GNU Parallel for each compilation unit in LLVM (parallel will automatically run 32 processes).

The following workloads are able to max out all cores continuously for 10min+:

- Clang compilation using Ninja. This workload is somewhat similar to indexing as it should be performing similar number of input operations; Kythe uses Clang internally to index the code. CPU temperatures hover around 75C - 80C. One probably irrelevant difference from running Kythe is that Kythe can generate indexes of around 300MB ~ 2.5GB *per* compilation unit, so I'm running Kythe under a small Python wrapper which creates a temporary file, lets Kythe write to it, and then deletes the file.
- GNU Parallel running a simple busy loop (incrementing a 1K vector element-wise for 5-15 seconds, which is approximately how long Kythe takes to index a compilation unit). Temperature is similar to above.

However, running Kythe under GNU Parallel causes some kind of throttling, where the CPUs get underclocked, and work is not assigned (using `sudo cpupower frequency-set -g performance` didn't help -- so it seems like the problem is that Kythe processes are getting penalized/deprioritized after a while, the browser also sees slowdown). The temperature drops to 60C or so.

[image: CPU throttling with Kythe]

In the above picture, the early part of the graph shows the GNU Parallel/Busy loop workload. I then terminate those processes and start the GNU Parallel/Kythe workload. For some reason, the Kythe workload runs into throttling issues which neither Clang nor the Busy loop workload run into. What could be causing this/how do I debug further?

### Reproduction steps

1. (Prep) Run the CMake command on the LLVM repo:

   ```bash
   git clone https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git --depth=1
   cd llvm-project/llvm
   CC=/usr/bin/clang-14 CXX=/usr/bin/clang++-14 cmake -B ../build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G Ninja -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=clang
   ```

   This will prepare a `../build/compile_commands.json` file.
2. (Prep) Download the Kythe release (e.g. under `$HOME/code`) and run the extractor as described in the Kythe docs.

   ```bash
   wget https://github.com/kythe/kythe/releases/download/v0.0.60/kythe-v0.0.60.tar.gz -o $HOME/code
   tar xzf $HOME/code/kythe-v0.0.60.tar.gz
   cd ../build
   mkdir kythe-v0.0.60-output
   KYTHE_ROOT_DIRECTORY=$PWD KYTHE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=$PWD/kythe-v0.0.60-output/ KYTHE_CORPUS=my-llvm $HOME/code/kythe-v0.0.60/tools/runextractor compdb -extractor $HOME/code/kythe-v0.0.60/extractors/cxx_extractor
   ```
3. (Actual workload) Run Kythe in parallel:

   ```py
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   # code/timing.py

   import sys
   import tempfile
   import time
   import subprocess
   import os
   from datetime import datetime

   input_file = sys.argv[1]
   _, output_file = tempfile.mkstemp(prefix="entries-")

   start = datetime.now()
   subprocess.run(["/home/varun/code/kythe-v0.0.60/indexers/cxx_indexer", "--ignore_unimplemented", input_file, "-o", output_file])
   end = datetime.now()
   delta = end - start

   input_size = os.stat(input_file).st_size
   output_size = os.stat(output_file).st_size
   print("{} bytes to {} bytes in {} sec from {}".format(input_size, output_size, delta.seconds, input_file))

   os.remove(output_file)
   ```

   ```bash
   parallel ~/code/timing.py ::: kythe-v0.0.60-output/*.kzip | tee timings.txt
   ```

Comment: Could you write tmp-files to a ram disk?

Answer (score 0):

> One probably irrelevant difference from running Kythe is that Kythe can generate indexes of around 300MB ~ 2.5GB per compilation unit, so I'm running Kythe under a small Python wrapper which creates a temporary file, lets Kythe write to it, and then deletes the file.

Turns out, this is very relevant. It is easy to check if this is causing the problem by creating a dummy script which mimics Kythe's high disk output and seeing if it causes similar throttling. Here is an example script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import tempfile
import time
import os
import random
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime

output_fd, output_file = tempfile.mkstemp(prefix="entries-")

size_100M = random.randint(5, 15)

start = datetime.now()

# Kythe can end up writing about 500MB - 1.5GB in a span of 5-15s.
# We mimic that workload by writing 1M every 0.01s, and just wasting
# some CPU if we're done writing early.

dummyvec = list(range(1024))

for i in range(size_100M * 100):
    iter_start = datetime.now()
    iter_end = iter_start + timedelta(milliseconds=10)
    os.write(output_fd, os.urandom(1024 * 1024))
    while datetime.now() < iter_end:
        # Waste CPU
        for i in range(len(dummyvec)):
            dummyvec[i] = (dummyvec[i] + 1) % 1024

end = datetime.now()
delta = end - start

output_size = os.stat(output_file).st_size
print("Wrote {} bytes in {} sec".format(output_size, delta.seconds))

os.remove(output_file)
```

This script can be run under `parallel` again:

```bash
parallel high_output.py ::: kythe-v0.0.60-output/*.kzip
```

If you start seeing timings which exceed 15 seconds, you know for sure that there is throttling happening.

Turns out, I started seeing times of over 20-25 seconds after the `parallel` command ran for a little bit.

---

It is important to look at other temperatures too, not just the CPU temperature. For example, you can use the `lm-sensors` package on Ubuntu to see temperatures across all the different sensors.

```bash
# Re-run sensors from lm-sensors every 2 seconds
watch -n 2 sensors
```

Turns out, the problem was with temperatures of the NVMe drive.

```
nvme-pci-0400                                                                                                  
Adapter: PCI adapter                                                                                           
Composite:    +55.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +81.8°C)                                                       
                       (crit = +84.8°C)                                                                        
Sensor 1:     +55.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)                                                    
Sensor 2:     +87.8°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
```

In a full-speed run, Kythe can end up writing 100MB/s of output per compilation unit. While this isn't so bad, having 32 processes means 3.2GB/s of output, which seemed to overwhelm the NVMe in my situation, leading to overheating. When the NVMe drive gets heated so much, Linux seems to throttle all running processes (explaining the browser slowdown).

For Kythe specifically, based on this [Google groups thread](https://groups.google.com/g/kythe/c/YJrfmovaWZ8), Kythe has a flag `--experimental_dynamic_claim_cache` which seems like it can potentially help reduce disk output, utilizing memcached under the hood.

Comment: `iostat -dkx 1` is often good at seeing if disk IO is the bottleneck.